# Using the same color for multiple plots if each dataset contains a common column

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two data frames with several columns.  I plot df#1 as as stacked bar plot and overlay df #2 as a line plot.  If a data series in df#1 is present in df#2 I want the color of the bar segment & line to be the same, for ease of comparison.  How would I do that?  Below, I would want the colors of 'FO' to be the same.

Data Frames:

```
df#1

            FO     MI
Date                     
08-Jan-23  0.4925  0.0000
15-Jan-23  0.9075  0.0000
22-Jan-23  0.9750  0.0250
29-Jan-23  0.9625  0.0375
05-Feb-23  0.9825  0.0000
```

```
df#2

           FO      AR
Jan-23     1.0     1.1
Feb-23     1.0     2.2
```

Here's my code:

```
    # Build a union of the dataframe columns so the line and bar series can have the same color
    # for ease of comparison
    df_Plot1 = vg.dc_dF_Groups[employee]
    cols = df_Plot.columns.union(df_Plot1.columns)  
    
    cmap = matplotlib.colormaps['Set1']
    colors = dict(zip(cols, cmap.colors))
    
    # Plot the employee's charges
    df_Plot.iloc[0:plotFinish].reindex(columns=cols).plot.bar(ax=ax1, color=df_Plot.columns.map(colors), rot=45, legend=True, xlabel='Date', ylabel='Actuals', alpha=0.5, stacked=True)

    # Plot the employee's group allocations
    df_Plot1.iloc[0:plotFinish].reindex(columns=cols).plot.line(ax=ax2, color=df_Plot1.columns.map(colors), ylabel='Allocation', legend=True, linewidth=3)
    ax1.legend(title='Actuals', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05,1.0), loc='upper left', ncol=1)
    ax2.legend(title='Allocations', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05,0.5), loc='upper left', ncol=1)
    fig.suptitle(employee)
```

Comment: please provide **minimal reproducible** examples of your two DataFrames

Comment: Added sample dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the column's [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
cols = df1.columns.union(df2.columns)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

df1.reindex(columns=cols).plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=axes[0])
df2.reindex(columns=cols).plot.line(ax=axes[1])
```

Output:

[image: colors common to two graphs]

Alternatively, create a custom list of colors and map them from the column names:

```
import matplotlib

cols = df1.columns.union(df2.columns)

cmap = matplotlib.colormaps['Set1']
colors = dict(zip(cols, cmap.colors))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

df1.plot.bar(stacked=True, color=df1.columns.map(colors), ax=axes[0])
df2.plot.line(color=df2.columns.map(colors), ax=axes[1])
```

Output:

[image: mapped colors common to two graphs]

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  Is there any way to hide the legend labels for data series that are not present in the respective plot?

Comment: @Jim sure, see another approach as edit

Comment: Thanks.  I've added that code (edited my post to include the updated code) but I still get the full legend for the line plot.

Comment: Make sure to run it in a clean interpreter with a fresh import of the data.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. Same result.  I see all the legend elements AND it no longer matches the colors between the two.

Comment: @Jim It's difficult to know what's going on without a reproducible example